# Connection refused.Check that hostname and port are correct and the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: postgresql, virtualbox, confluence

I have Virtual Box installed where two instances of Centos are running. Lets 
call them Centos 1 and Centos 2. I have successfully setup Confluence application on Centos with localhost Postgres DB in Centos 1.

The Problem:

When I am trying to setup confluence in Centos 2 it requires DB Connection If I provide the URL with the jdbc syntax it does not connect to the DB instance of Centos 1.

JDBC URL:  `jdbc:postgresql://192.168.56.13:5432/confluence`

> The Error:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused.Check that hostname and port are correct and the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

The nmap command from instance two to instance 1 is successful.

I am trying to edit the configuration as shown below
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-postgresql-jdbc-direct-connection-refused-683543784.html

But I get a error when I give the command service postgresql restart
I guess it is not taking my entry of
host all all 192.168.56.105 trust

Please Clarify.

Comment: Can you show us the full stacktrace of the error? I'm sure there is more information. Did you disable the firewall on DB server?

Comment: Thats the only information I have regarding the error.

Comment: Thats the only information I have regarding the error.Disabled the firewall. If you edit the pg_hba.conf  you can find that a new Entry needs to be updated in postgresql file with the IP address as shown here https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-postgresql-jdbc-direct-connection-refused-683543784.html This gives a error any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all `peer` authentication entries with `md5` in your postgres's `pg_hba.conf` file. this way the authorization will work

Comment: Tried changing from trust to md5 still gives a error Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Comment: find the postgres daemon error log file . you will find why it is happening

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I'm doing this first time and this doesn't help me, not at all.